# Coloration for a variable list of element?

Tags: c#, wpf, colors

I have a class Product .

```
public class Product
{
 public int Id { get; set; }
 public string Name { get; set; }  <-- 
 ......
}
```

I have a database table that contains the list of products and this list grows each time I add a new product. 
In my application I have a chart that use the list of product, I want to color each product
with a specific color but the number of product can increase dynamically. For instance, I can have in the first run of the application:

```
Product A --> color blue 
Product B --> color Brown
Product C --> color red
Product A--> color Blue
```

But In the next run (suppose I add a new product D)

```
Product A --> color blue 
Product B --> color Brown
Product C --> color red
Product A --> color Blue
Product D --> color Black
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
   List<string> colorsList=new List();
   colorList.add("black");
   colorList.add("blue");
```

Simple 
you can use many types of collection ,There are many tutorials out there on google
it depends on your Requirements
Forexample :you want to access some class Color Object from color Name or another string.you can use Dictionary

```
    Dictionary<string ,ColorClass> Dictionary and so on
```

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/csharp/csharp_collections.htm
http://www.dotnetperls.com/collections

Comment: what about the product name

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need to use a `Dictionary`

```
Dictionary<string, string> ProductColor= new Dictionary<string, string>();
ProductColor.Add("apple", "blue");
ProductColor.Add("windows", "red");
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not fully clear what you want to achieve, but if you need to create a random color for a particular item, you could use the [Random class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.random%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for it with the [Color class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.colors%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), something like this:

```
var rnd = new Random();
var color = Color.FromArgb(rnd.Next(0, 255), rnd.Next(0, 255), rnd.Next(0, 255), rnd.Next(0, 255));
```

After that, just add it to your product class (if you have a property for it), create a new class containing Product and Color and use a list with that entity or use a Dictionary containing your product and the color (`Dictionary<Color, Product>`).